# jQuery Click/Change event not working properly in IE7/8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, checkbox, jquery-events

I am binding an event to a checkbox's change or click event which works fine in Firefox but in IE I have to click anywhere else (causing the blur) event before the event is fired.

I have read and believe this is down to the way IE fires the events, but is there anyway I can get round it?

The whole point is that it is a smooth search feature which doesn't need a search button to be clicked

```
$('#sidebar .itemSearchModule-Form input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
    $('#sidebar .itemSearchModule-Form .saveButton').click();
});
```

Comment: Can you post your code?  I've used the click event on a checkbox in IE6 and IE7 without any troubles.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/ovexi "click" works fine for me on IE6/IE7

Answer (score 1):

The change event requires a blur to happen first. The Click event should not. You could always force a `blur` event if you wanted by `$(elem).blur()`

Answer (score 1):

Paolo Bergantino was right so this answer credit should go to him.

It seems my code was all screwed up and another selector was getting tied up with the sample I used above.

The CLICK event does work in IE I can confirm, if you are suffering the same problem ALL I can suggest is you check your code

Answer (score 0):

try giving that checkbox a class like `chkbx` and try:

```
$('.chkbx').click(function() { etc...
```

its just for debuggin your selector.. being sure problem is in the action. i think for IE you need to use GetElementByID.